# Limit contenteditable span to 5 numerical characters in length

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to limit the contenteditable span shown below to just 5 characters (4 numerals and a dash). The user needs to be able to input years from -9999 B.C.E. to the current year 2013. A dash before the year would indicate a B.C.E. year. Anything without a dash would be an A.D. year.

these would all be acceptable entries:

-9546
-765
-1
0
25
125
2013

```
<div class="HYPE_element" id="start_year" style="pointer-events: auto; top: 0px; left: 120px; position: absolute; padding: 8px; overflow: visible; word-wrap: break-word; display: inline; z-index: 5; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(120, 204, 187);">
<span contenteditable="true" class="numeric">2013</span>
</div>
```

Right now anyone can add letters numbers characters, and also, the span just keeps expanding to the right.

I used this to limit the length of characters to 5.

```
var content_id = 'start_year';  
    max = 4;
    //binding keyup/down events on the contenteditable div
    $('#'+content_id).keyup(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });
    $('#'+content_id).keydown(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });
    function check_charcount(content_id, max, e)
    {   
        if(e.which != 8 && $('#'+content_id).text().length > max)
        {
           // $('#'+content_id).text($('#'+content_id).text().substring(0, max));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

However I'm not sure how to limit the characters entered to just numbers and a dash.

Answer (score 0):

Not many browsers support this but....

```
<input type="number" max="9999"  min="-9999"/>
```

Comment: I would prefer to stay away from input textfields. I've alread got the character length taken care of, so the min and max number is not a concern. What I am concerned with is limiting input to just "0-9" and a dash "-"